# Sending a message to a specific channel with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a modmail bot with discord.py, but I'm trying to send a message from DM to a specific channel in a server. I have tried the following:

```py
@bot.command()
async def startcase(ctx, *args):
  channel = client.get_channel(XXXXXX)
  mesg = ' '.join(args)
  await ctx.channel.send(mesg)
```

Comment: What is your problem? What error are you encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the channel from the [`Context.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.channel) attribute, which will be the channel where the command was sent, rather than the `channel` you got from [`Client.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel), to send the message.